# How to rename(branding) browser built on Android Chromium source code?

Tags: android, google-chrome

I need to build custom browser based on android chromium with custom product name.
I found config files(src/chrome/app/theme/chromium/BRANDING) and changed PRODUCT_FULLNAME. 
Then I have built APK with commands

```
src$ gclient sync
src$ ninja -C out/Release chrome_public_apk
```

in console.

Build completes without errors.
But after installation on target device, I saw default product name.

Configurations in src/build/common.gypi:

- 'branding%' : 'Chromium'
- 'buildtype%' : 'Dev'
- 'component%' : 'static_library'

chromium.gyp_env: { 'GYP_DEFINES': 'OS=android' }

What i do wrong? How rebrand chromium?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

that package name string is defined in [//chrome/android/BUILD.gn](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/64baf01809ec9265017ce344d306497b2f855d38/chrome/android/BUILD.gn#22).